# footcite works bad in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, itemize

When using `\footcite` inside `itemize` environment in a `beamer` document in this way:

```
%beamer document
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item a\footcite{citation}.
    \item b
    \end{itemize}
```

something strange happens: citation change its aspect when moving of frame. Below I provide an image.

[image]

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{csquotes} %"para citar bien"

\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{trochine2014benznidazole,
  Title                    = {Benznidazole biotransformation and multiple targets in Trypanosoma cruzi revealed by metabolomics},
  Author                   = {Trochine, Andrea and Creek, Darren J and Faral-Tello, Paula and Barrett, Michael P and Robello, Carlos},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {e2844},
  Volume                   = {8},

  Journal                  = {PLoS Negl Trop Dis},
  Publisher                = {Public Library of Science}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{benznidazol}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item a\footcite{trochine2014benznidazole}.
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Maybe there is a problem of compatibility between `itemize` and `\footcite` but don't have idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\footfullcite{trochine2014benznidazole}`, the command will prevent biblatex to make a short citation the second time.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected. The `verbose` style shows a full citation only upon the first citation, subsequent calls to the a work are shortened to 'author+title'.

You can turn off the the citation tracking responsible for this with the option `citetracker=false`.

Alternatively, you can make all citations long with the redefinition

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full}}
```